# writing greek letters with subscripts with matplotlib

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib

I have to use greek letter with subscript as axes label, so i thought to use Latex symbols. I am using the following code:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

and in the plot I have, for example:

```
ylabel(r'$\boldsymbol{\delta_y}$')
```

It works fine, it is just slow (it take about 5 sec. to make a plot), I guess it is bacause python has to call an external package.

Any chances I can make it faster?

I am using python 2.6

Comment: It shouldn't be slow every time, only the first time it makes the label. Matplotlib caches results of TeX on most systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `rc('text', usetex=False)`.

With this matplotlib will use the internal `mathtext` instead of your OS's latex installation to render math symbols. See the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/usetex.html).